# Asp.net GridView Get DropDownList value from itemlist on edit row

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu

Im trying to update a cell from from DropdownList control which is using item list, but when i select value and click on update, the updated cell is empty:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Done BY">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblUser" width="100px" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("User")%>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListUser" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
            <asp:ListItem Value="Alex" Text="Alex"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="Yan" Text="Yan"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="Yagi" Text="Yagi"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownListUser_SelectedIndexChanged"`    to your code, and write the following code on the server side. This will let you change the name dynamically and post it on the label;

```
protected void DropDownListUser_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblUser.Text = DropDownListUser.SelectedValue.ToString();    
}
```